# Parameter type lookup for out-of-namespace function definitions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

The software project I lead occasionally uses nested namespaces as a means of indicating which parts of the library are intended to be internal and should not be considered user-facing.  For example:

```
namespace project::detail {
  // Hands off; library implementation internals
  class Internal {};
  int important_number(Internal internals);      
}
```

Before C++17, the indentation would become somewhat dreadful (depending on the source code formatting), so we opted for defining functions out-of-namespace:

```
int 
project::detail::important_number(Internal const internals) 
{ ... }
```

Observe that although the type `Internal` was declared and defined in the `project::detail` nested namespace, it is not required to fully qualify the parameter type (i.e.):

```
int
project::detail::important_number(/*unnecessary*/ project::detail::Internal)
```

I have scoured [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) and bits of the C++14 standard and have not found the place(s) that support the abbreviated function definition (the first example above).  I am assuming the relevant rules did not change for C++17.  Can anyone tell me which rules of the C++14/17 standard apply here--i.e. where does the standard support non-fully-qualified parameter types for out-of-namespace function definitions?

Comment: For future reference, cppreference.com gives the particular rules for this situation in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for *unqualified name lookup* and it can be found in the standard under [basic.lookup.unqual](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual)

> In the definition of a function that is a member of namespace `N`, a
>   name used after the function’s *declarator-id* shall be declared before
>   its use in the block in which it is used or in one of its enclosing
>   blocks  or shall be declared before its use in namespace `N` or, if
>   `N` is a nested namespace, shall be declared before its use in one of
>   `N`’s enclosing namespaces.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing the sentence--that appears to be referring to names used in a "block" or a nested "block."  But this is the use of the typename before the block--i.e. in the function type.  What am I getting wrong?

Comment: The standardese basically says that the declaration of `Internal` being used in `important_number` must appear in the nested namespace `detail` before being used by the definition of `important_number` (it is). So unqualified name lookup will successfully search the nested `detail` namespace of `project` and find `Internal`

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel I think `block in which it is used` and `enclosing blocks` basically just refer to the cases of e.g. local variable declarations in the function body. They do not really apply in the parameter list.